# Facebook Connect on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I'm new in iOS development. I want to connect my App to Facebook. [Implement Facebook Connect on the iPhone](http://vimeo.com/3616452)

I have followed [iPhone FBConnect: Facebook Connect Tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/) and done every steps that described there.

But I couldn't run the App because I have two errors which are `Semantic Issues` in my xCode 4.3.3, In `FBConnectGlobal.h` on these lines:

```
typedef unsigned long long FBUID;
typedef unsigned long long FBID;
```

The error message is : *Redefinition of typedef `FBUID` and `FBID` is invalid in C*

I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FBGraph API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/59e639922c4bf6953162ea81998f2ff951cd1769) link as it has demo and it is very easy to integrate and use

Comment: I followed the link, it was useful, the matter is I need to create a `Login` and `SignIn` mechanism on my own. Do you know how can I use `FBGraph API`? How can I write the query using FBGraph?

Comment: check this answer by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805078/login-to-facebook-using-fbgraph/11805615#11805615

Comment: The first link was useful for me, but the second one is not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I use ShareKit, that is very easy and simple to implement, having many social networks and not only Facebook:

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Please follow these instructions to the letter:

```
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I got an `uncategorized` error : `../../ShareKit-ShareKit-7a05403/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/../../../../../Submodules/facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBDialog.bundle: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please follow these instructions to the letter:https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit