# Login to Facebook using FBGraph

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I am new in iOS development. I want to connect to Facebook from my iPhone app. I followed [FBGraph API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/59e639922c4bf6953162ea81998f2ff951cd1769) to see how we can use Facebook in our App like:

Prints the information of user which is logged in:

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me" withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

or the list of friends:

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeFriendsButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

And this is `doGraphGet` method in `FbGraph.m`:

```
- (FbGraphResponse *)doGraphGet:(NSString *)action withGetVars:(NSDictionary *)get_vars {

    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?", action];

    //tack on any get vars we have...
    if ( (get_vars != nil) && ([get_vars count] > 0) ) {

        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [get_vars keyEnumerator];
        NSString *key;
        NSString *value;
        while ((key = (NSString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {

            value = (NSString *)[get_vars objectForKey:key];
            url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@=%@&", url_string, key, value];

        }//end while    
    }//end if

    if (accessToken != nil) {
        //now that any variables have been appended, let's attach the access token....
        url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@access_token=%@", url_string, self.accessToken];
    }
```

First we need to Login to Facebook as shown:

[image]

I guess that it uses this code in FbGraph.m (using `UIWebView`) :

```
self.redirectUri = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

- (void)authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:(id)anObject andSelector:(SEL)selector andExtendedPermissions:(NSString *)extended_permissions andSuperView:(UIView *)super_view {

    self.callbackObject = anObject;
    self.callbackSelector = selector;

    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&type=user_agent&display=touch", facebookClientID, redirectUri, extended_permissions];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    CGRect webFrame = [super_view frame];

    webFrame.origin.y = 0;
    UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [aWebView setDelegate:self];    
    self.webView = aWebView;

    [aWebView release];

    [webView loadRequest:request];  
    [super_view addSubview:webView];
}
```

My question is about a possibility. Can I have a mechanism on my own that get the email and password from the user and then login (like the other methods for instance print in the console that Authenication failed or successfull Login)?

Answer (score 0):

On click of button and its event is say fbLogin then  add this code for login

```
-(void)fbLogin
{
   if(!self.fbGraph.accesstoken) // doesnot have access token. So needed to login
   {
    NSString *client_id = @"130902823636657"; //get your own client id from facebook

    //alloc and initalize our FbGraph instance
    self.fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];

    //begin the authentication process.....
    [self.fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];
   }
   else
   {
      // Add UIAlert as user is logged in already
      //pop a message letting them know most of the info will be dumped in the log
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note" message:@"user is logged in already" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
   }
}
```

Now when user is authebticated this method below is called. So add this method in your .h file.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FbGraph Callback Function
/**
* This function is called by FbGraph after it's finished the authentication process
**/
- (void)fbGraphCallback:(id)sender 
{

 if ( (self.fbGraph.accessToken == nil) || ([self.fbGraph.accessToken length] == 0) ) 
 {

  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note" message:@"Try Again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];

  //restart the authentication process.....
  //[self.fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];

 } 
 else 
 {
  //pop a message letting them know most of the info will be dumped in the log
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note" message:@"Logged In Successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
  NSLog(@"------------>CONGRATULATIONS<------------, You're logged into Facebook... Your oAuth token is: %@", self.fbGraph.accessToken);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is just a copy from `viewDidAppear` and `fbGraphCallback` in the [FBGraph API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/59e639922c4bf6953162ea81998f2ff951cd1769). :) Take a look at the end of the question. I asked about possibility of creating my own Login wizard not using the Facebook wizard in the photo.

Comment: And the things is it may not be possible.