# How to Login to Facebook and Go Back to Application

Tags: objective-c, protocols

This is what I wanna do. User press Sign in Via facebook. I do:

```
Facebook * facebook =[[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:api_key andDelegate:self];;
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
}
```

If I do that I go to safary. The page says that I authorized my application.

User then has to press Okay to go back to my application.

While it make sense to do so for the first time, it's cumbersome to do it again and again.

What about if I don't want that? What about if I want users to just go directly to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Facebook-Graph-API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/59e639922c4bf6953162ea81998f2ff951cd1769) for your requirement.

Refer [login-to-facebook-using-fbgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805615/1106035) link.

Comment: I thought I am using Facebook Graph API. Previous programmer take care of it. How do I know?