# Facebook Login with iOS facebook application doesn't go back to my application after authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I am using Latest iOS facebook sdk and connecting to facebook on my application start screen.It is using iOS facebook Application for the facebook login, and if I am already logged in to facebook then it works well the user authenticates and it goes back to my application but if I am not logged in to iOS facebook application then after user authentication it doesn't go back to my application :(

I have already added FacebookAppID, URL Identifier and URL Schemes in plist but no Luck :(
Also I have added this method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *) sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"The URL is %@",url.absoluteString);
    NSLog(@"The Source Application is %@",sourceApplication);


    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Someone plz suggest me the fix of this issue.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065714/how-to-login-to-facebook-and-go-back-to-application ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *appId = @"Your app Id";NSString *permissions = @"publish_stream";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, appId, redirectUrlString, permissions];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[fbwebview loadRequest:request];


//    then Implement the webview Methods,In
  - (void)getFacebookProfileFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    [self CallServiceforYourApp];
}
```