# Facebook share post including text under url

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, social-networking

This is the post which i want to get from my app on facebook, but i am not able to add the message("This is my Message") under the url, i was able to post the url and title using the code below :

[image: Post Should Look like this on Fb]

Here is my void method to post on Fb

```
-(void)fb_share
{
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"Cancelled");

        } else

        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;


    [controller setInitialText:@"This is my title"];


    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pinterest.com"]];
   // [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}

}
```

This code me gives this result :

[image]

But i don't want the post to be like this, i want to give my own message under the url(Like "This is my Message"), plz can any one tell me how can i do that programatically.. Thank you in Advance

Comment: i know that but you can do that, because you can do that on facebook while u post a link, so if it can be done their, so why not in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative is to use [iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/59e639922c4bf6953162ea81998f2ff951cd1769) as easy to use.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

[variables setObject:@"MESSAGE HERE" forKey:@"message"];
[variables setObject:@"URL HERE" forKey:@"link"];
[variables setObject:@"URL NAME HERE" forKey:@"name"];
[variables setObject:@"URL DESC HERE." forKey:@"description"];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
```

**EDIT** : Refer [login-to-facebook-using-fbgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805615/1106035) link.

Comment: is their any other method than this one?

Comment: check FBGraph API Document if there is any another message sharing any link.

Comment: ok .. i have social framework and Facebook SDK in my project, now what steps should i take to invoke the GraphAPI if i have already logged in?